# AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a very weird issue in my Django project.

Here is my **model**:

```
class Connection(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='exchange_connections', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange, related_name='connection_exchange', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
```

Here is my **serialiser**:

```
class ConnectionSer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Connection
        fields = '__all__'
```

And my **view**:

```
class UserPortfolioViewSet(views.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ConnectionSer
    queryset = Connection.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, core_permissions.IsMineOnly)

    def list(self, request):
        try:
            user = request.user
        except:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest('No user')

        connections = user.exchange_connections.all()

        return Response(self.serializer_class(connections).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I get this **error** from the view (GET):

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on
> serializer `ConnectionSer`. The serializer field might be named
> incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet`
> instance. Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no
> attribute 'user'.

Which makes no sense to me because I don't create any exchange property in my serializer class..?
And I also don't understand the last line: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'.`

Comment: Why not use a `ModelViewSet` instead?

Comment: @Daniel because I'm trying several things and forgot to put `ModelViewSet` back.

Comment: I see - I am not sure what your `list` method is doing, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by passing a collection/list of `Connection` instances to the serializer, but not flagging the serializer to use `many=True`, so just add that to prevent the error:

```
        return Response(self.serializer_class(connections, many=True).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                                                          # ^^^ Add this
```

But other than that, @Daniel's answer would be a better way to go to let the `ModelViewSet` handle all the serialization for you.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me after trying so many things. What an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to filter your queryset based on the active user. You can override the `get_queryset` method to do this. Furthermore, you already have the `IsAuthenticated` permission class on your ViewSet, so you don't need to check for active user:

```py
class UserPortfolioViewSet(views.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):

        # get the queryset:
        queryset = self.queryset

        # get the active user:
        user = self.request.user

        # filter queryset based on user:
        queryset = quseryset.filter(user=user)

        # return the fitlered queryset:
        return queryset
```